# For Each Shortcut Key Press Copy Column To The Right

Tags: excel, vba

Okay so below you can find a screenshot and the code I have.

Basically, I have two workbooks

- What I have is workbook where I have macro with a shortcut (CTRL-SHIFT-M) this macro needs to open second workbook (data.xlsm) select and copy the first column, 01/15 (as you can see below), then I will need to do something manually with the copied content, and after I press the shortcut again, it will move onto another column -> to the right and again select and copy that column, and repeat.

My sheet with columns

[image]

My code:

```
Sub Copy_From_Another_Workbook()


Copy_From_Another_Workbook Macro

Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M

Dim radky As Range
Set radky = Range("I04:I409")

souborData = "C:\Users\cza19785\Desktop\Data.xlsm"
souborReport = "C:\Users\cza19785\Desktop\konsolidovaný report_VBA.xlsm"


Workbooks.Open (souborData)
Set souborData = ActiveWorkbook
radky.Select.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Tom welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? What is your script doing or not doing as you would like? Presumably you want to copy the active column into the workbook containing the macro but you don't say this. Make it clear what you want so that others know how to help you.   Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.